# Get sparse region of KDE

Tags: python, dataframe, scipy, kernel-density, anomaly-detection

I have an array of 20k real numbers, and I use `pd.DataFrame(scores).plot.kde(figsize=(24,8))` to get the below kernel density estimation. How can I purely programmatically select the indexes of the sparse regions, or conversely the dense region?

My current approach is of the form `np.where(scores > np.percentile(scores, 99))[0]`, I am very of such hard cording of `99` as it may not work too well in production. A potential solution which I'm not sure how to approach is selecting the indices where the Density is below 20,000

[image]

Comment: You could use scipys KDE instead and that will give you the values directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which region to consider "sparse" and which "dense" can be very subjective. It also heavily depends on the signification of the data. An idea is to decide upon some cut-off percentiles. The example below uses the lowest `0.1 %` and highest `99.9 %`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'score': np.random.randn(2000, 10).cumsum(axis=0).ravel()})
df['score'].quantile([.01, .99])
ax = df.plot.kde(figsize=(24, 8))
ax.axvline(df['score'].quantile(.001), color='crimson', ls=':')
ax.axvline(df['score'].quantile(.999), color='crimson', ls=':')
ax.set_ylim(ymin=0) # avoid the kde "floating in the air"
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Was this answer helpful?